# How can I add clone counter id in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know where to put the counter;
    The next cloned id must be gender_1

Example:

`<select id="gender">`

```
Next is:
`<select id="gender_1">`

then:
`<select id="gender_2">`
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f7hjh1gf/6/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f7hjh1gf/6/

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Relevant code belongs directly into your question, and not just on external sites only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, before append to the element you need to replace the cloned selected element `id` using `find()` function and update the `id` incremented using `c++`

[**Updated jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/f7hjh1gf/7/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var c=1;
    $(document).on('click', '#mode', function(){
        $("#notok").clone(true).find('select').attr('id','gender_'+(c++) ).closest('.ok').appendTo("#clones");
    });
});
```

Comment: I think op was missing with jquery tag..he was full coded with jquery function.

Comment: @J.A.Manato, you have also not marked the answer in your previous post, you should mark answer or upvote if any of the post or reply helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you add a clone get the number of clones already present and increment it by one before adding it to "gender_", you can use `$("#clones div").length` to get number of clones currently present.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#mode', function(){
        $("#notok").clone(true).attr('id', "gender_"+($("#clones div").length + 1)).appendTo("#clones");
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="ok" id="notok">
 <select id="gender">
     <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>

    
</div>

<div id=clones></div>

<button id="mode">Clone</button>


  

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```